# Enterprise Architect prevent extended metaclass through derivation

Tags: enums, enterprise-architect, metaclass

I have an element `Enum` which derrivates from an abstract Element `Type`.

This Type extends the Metaclass `DataType` and this is a necessity for me.

Is it now possible to extend the `Enum`, but not from this DataType?

I can only add another Metaclass and extend the `Enum` from it. But then after exporting the profile diagram, I have two different Elements: one based on DataType and one based on Enumeration.

I only want the last one!

Can you help me solve this? Thank you!

Comment: Maybe you can post screenshots of your definition. I'm not sure about your question.

Comment: I cannot post images: but here is a link for an example: http://imgur.com/EggxpsM.png

Comment: are you trying to do stereotypes?

Comment: In the picture, you see two stereotypes (Type and Enum). That is not the problem.

Comment: No but I didn't realize until now that you were trying to make a UML profile, which would have been useful information because now this whole question makes more sense to me

Comment: @ThomasKilian UML profiles are not a Sparx EA Exclusivity AFAIK

Comment: @Mart10 Yes, it's a general concept. But the OP has technical trouble with the Sparxian way to create the right profile. Anyhow, he should clarify his question by posting appropriate screen shots first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have them generalize a common stereotype.

In this example, Enum will Inherit the Standard TaggedValue without getting the DataType metaclass. Type will also get the Standard TaggedValue

Please note that Common would not be usable has a stereotype as it does not extend a metaclass
[image]

Comment: Thank you, for this solution.

Comment: But i had hoped, there is another solution. Where i can use my diagram and simply exclude the DataType metaclass through Enterprise Architect.

Comment: @JanJJ Well this is the easiest and proper way, its not because this is a UML profile that this is not Object Oriented